# Azure Dev Ops Continuous Deployment pipeline "Job is pending..." error without any logs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, azure-service-principal

Azure Dev Ops (AzDO) Continuous Deployment on AKS pipeline doesn't run, stops at "Job is pending..." with a grey (X) icon and no logs:

[image: Job is pending... deployment failed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix (checklist):

- if using AzDO Environment "Approvals and checks" make sure AKS resource is added to the environment - found this was missing thanks to [Richard mentioning env's in his blog post](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2022/04/07/fixe-for-azure-devops-deployment-to-an-environment-stuck-in-job-is-pending-state/)

[image: empty environment - no aks]

- if using AzDO Library Variable Groups connected to Key Vaults make sure they are linked to a subscription - in my case the variables were visible from previous sync, but the subscription was missing because I have recreated the ARM service connection during troubleshooting. BTW make sure all kv- related vg's are fixed, I was missing one the whole time :)

[image: empty subscription box in key vault bound variable group]

(^ this should not be empty even if secrets are listed from previous binding... and make sure it's ok in all variable groups referenced from the pipeline)

---

In my case two service principals' credentials were expiring close in time, AKS SP and AzDO ARM Service Connection SP, so it was a bit tricky (or I might have just gotten lost in the details).

Anyway, here is (more or less) how I tackled the issue (plus some good links):

1. AKS Service Principal secret expired => [secret renewal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials) => it didn't help because point (2) => I didn't know about point (2) so I just recreated Kubernetes AzDO Service Connection => environment was empty => [read Richard's post](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2022/04/07/fixe-for-azure-devops-deployment-to-an-environment-stuck-in-job-is-pending-state/) => fixed environment => still nothing => found out about point (2)
2. AzDO Azure Resource Manager Service Connection token expired (probably, at this moment in time I am guessing, I'll admit) => read [service principal token renewal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#service-principals-token-expired) => not sure why it didn't help at that point, maybe it also killed VG<->sub association, I did not check VG's at that time => tried recreating the connection (it's the connection to the subscription) => this definitely removed the association between Key Vault bound Variable Groups and the subscription => read [MSDN pipeline troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#cant-access-azure-key-vault-behind-firewall-from-azure-devops) => thought hey let's check key vaults => didn't help => then I made sure I checked *all* the Key Vaults => et voilà, this finally helped, yay!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I incorrectly specified a [steps.download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-download?view=azure-pipelines) task.

Instead doing:

```yaml
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: my_artifact
```

I did:

```yaml
steps:
- download: my_artifact
```